# Different behavior with echo vs echo|cat when reading to / writing from FIFOs (pipes)

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, pipeline, named-pipes

I'm trying to understand the reason why `echo` behaves differently than `echo "Hi"|cat` when used in a bash script, with broken pipe

*Behaviour* :

1. `echo` immediately terminates the script
2. `echo "Hi"|cat` the pipeline terminates but the script continues

### Sample reproducing steps

*script_with_echo.sh* :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo ii
cat<ii >/dev/null & echo "KILL : $!"
exec 3>ii
rm ii
while true; do read LINE; echo "$LINE" >&3; echo "$?">/some/external/file;done
```

*script_with_echo_cat.sh* :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo ii
cat<ii >/dev/null & echo "KILL : $!"
exec 3>ii
rm ii
while true; do read LINE; echo "$LINE"|cat>&3; echo "$?">/some/external/file;done
```

1. run a script on terminal-1 (note `KILL : <PID>`)
2. input some sample lines to terminal-1 and verify that `0` (success exit code) is being written to `/some/external/file`
3. run `kill -9 <PID>` from terminal-2
4. input another sample line on terminal-1
5. - If `script_with_echo.sh` was being executed in step 1, **the script immediately terminates** (and no error code is written to `/some/external/file`)
   - If `script_with_echo_cat.sh` was being executed in step 1, **the script continues normally** (and for every subsequent sample line inputs, error code 141 (`SIGPIPE`) is being written to `/some/external/file`, which is expected)

**Why does this different behavior arise?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why echo behaves differently than echo "Hi"|cat when used in a bash script

In the case of `echo >&3` when the pipe connect to 3rd file descriptor is closed, then the bash process is killed by SIGPIPE. This is mostly because `echo` is a builtin command - it is executed by bash itself without any `fork()`ing.

In the case of `echo | cat >&3` when the pipe connected to 3rd file descriptor is closed, then the child process `cat` is killed by `SIGPIPE`, in which case the parent process continues to live, so Bash can handle the exit status.

Compare `strace -ff bash -c 'mkfifo ii; cat <ii >/dev/null & pid=$! ; exec 3>ii ; kill $pid ; rm ii ; echo something >&3'` vs `....; /bin/echo something >&3'`.

Comment: I had similar thoughts, but `which echo` outputs `/bin/echo` on my system, does bash use builtin regardless?

Comment: @MadhuchhandaMandal, use `type echo`, not `which echo`. `which` doesn't have any knowledge of shell builtins, shell functions, aliases, etc; being an external command itself, it _only_ checks the PATH, so if something exists both as a shell builtin and an external command, `which` will only know about the external-command form.

Comment: @MadhuchhandaMandal, ...btw, if you're coming from zsh, `which` is a builtin there, which might be where you got the idea that it could see shell internal state. That's very much zsh-exclusive, though; everywhere else I know of it's an external command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy exactly!!  `type which` clarified it now :)